# What is the definition of "finite" measure in the 6.10 theorem RCA(real and complex analysis)?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

6.10 theorem is the theorem of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym

> Let $\mu$ be a positive $\sigma$-finite measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ on a set $X$, and let $\lambda$ be the complex measure on $\mathfrak{M}$.
>
> 1. Then there is a unique pair of complex measures $\lambda_a,\lambda_s$ on $\mathfrak{M}$, called the \textbf{Lebesgue decomposition} of $\lambda$ relative to $\mu$, such that
>
> - $\lambda = \lambda_a + \lambda_s$
> - $\lambda_a\ll \mu$
> - $\lambda_s\perp \mu$
> - if $\lambda$ is positive and finite then so are $\lambda_a,\lambda_s$
>
> 2. There is a unique $h\in L^1(\mu)$ such that
>    $$\lambda_a(E) = \int_Ehd\mu$$
>    for every $E\in\mathfrak{M}$.

I don't know what the definition of 'finte' is in "if $\lambda$ is positive and finite then so are $\lambda_a,\lambda_s$". Do I have to think the same way as "bounded"?

Comment: A positive measure $\lambda$ on $X$ is called  a finite measure if $\lambda (X) <\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finite complex measure $\lambda$ is a measure whose imaginary and real parts are both finite-valued signed measures (i.e. $|\lambda_{real}(X)|, |\lambda_{imag}(X)| < \infty$) where $|\cdot|$ just refers to the usual absolute value.